# Angular 2 use the source code in your project

Tags: javascript, debugging, angular, npm

I am installing Angular with npm:

```
npm install @angular...
```

The problem is the typescript source files does not include there. I want to be able to debug code with the typescript source files ( with the source maps ).
For example cloning the repo and use this code. There is a way do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no package '@angular' in the npm registry. Refer to this the [angular quickstart guide](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json). Update your package.json with this (this is all the @angular dependencies), then `npm install` will give you the typescript.

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.3.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  }
```

Don't forget to set up the mappings in system js

```
map: {
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    }
```

Comment: You can explain why your solution is different from npm?

Comment: There is no package '@angular' in the npm registry, it shouldn't be installing anything.